# Good way to display a folder in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, filesystems

i need to display a folder in myViewController same as displaying folder in our System/Computer.
and also i need to drag a image to this folder.i have folder named as static in app-bundle.
so when i drag a image on to the folder,need to save the dragged image to app-bundle static folder.

i know the code to save.however what is  the best method to display a folder in myViewController.is it like a button with folder image or any controller to show a folder?

i think can use - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event; to drag a image over folder.and check if it touches the folder frame .if yes,save it to the appbundle.is it a good way?and can any one tell me a good way to display a folder in myViewController.

Comment: wen ever ur satisfy with answer select any one of the answer..

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is pan gesture instead of touches moved.you can implement same as like your desktop.take an image  and place in your view controller and give action for the image and whenever any object touches your static folder(already we placed image) change the touched object path.its so simple seems to be.

Comment: any sample app or link using pan gesture

Comment: UIPanGestureRecognizer *panOnStartImage = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanOnFolder:)];
  panOnStartImage.delegate=self;
  [urfolderImage addGestureRecognizer:panOnStartImage];
  [self.view addSubview:startImage];
  [panOnStartImage release];

Comment: above i gave code for applying a pan gesture  for the folder..you can use handlePanOnFolder: method to operate ur folder to move..

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are asking the wrong question. From the user's perspective, iOS doesn't have a filesystem or folders or files or save buttons. Sure, you *could* create a view that looks like a folder with files in it... but you shouldn't.

My recommendation is that you rethink your design and accomplish what you need to do by using the new iOS paradigms instead of trying to replicate the old desktop paradigms.